# mysql create database incorrect name

Tags: mysql, database

For example, when I go to the mysql command line and do:

```
mysql> create database `#mysql#testdb`;
```

and try:

```
mysql> show databases;
```

I only get a db named "testdb" and NOT "#mysql#testdb".

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You use special characters like # (sql comments). If you can avoid it, use the underscore '_' instead of #. Otherwise, look at [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html), it should help you to use the special characters.

Answer (score 2):

`#` is a mysql comment notation.  you're commenting out the mysql, basically.